# How do I use Ninject to inject a static property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2 to implement a web service and I have a custom `JsonResult` class:

```
public abstract class JsonResult : ActionResult
{
    public static ISerializer Serializer { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var json = Serializer.Serialize(this);
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(json);
    }
}
```

`JsonResult` is the abstract base class for all results that should be serialized into JSON data. It usesan `ISerializer` to do the serialization.

I'm using Ninject as my IoC container. However, I'm not really sure how I should be injecting the `ISerializer` dependency. I was originally doing this:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel().Bind<ISerializer>().To<JsonNetSerializer>();
JsonResult.Serializer = kernel.Get<ISerializer>();
```

But something about it just doesn't seem quite right. So how would I go about injecting the `Serializer` property correctly? I want to inject it only once when the application starts up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, MVC is not my league, but is there some reason why you can't remove the `static` modifier, set lifetime of `JsonNetSerializer` to be singleton, and have that injected into the constructor of `JsonResult`? Note in particular this makes the dependency on `ISerializer` explicit (a good thing) and avoids `static` (a good thing).

Comment: So does this mean that, in order to keep the `Serializer` property as a singleton, I have to always use an IoC container to instantiate an instance of `JsonResult`?

Comment: @Daniel T.: Preferably you should use a factory. So if you have a class that is instantiating `ConcreteJsonResult`, it should take a `JsonResultFactory`. Of course, you can just make `JsonResultFactory.Create<TJsonResult>` along the lines of `return kernel.Get<TJsonResult>();`.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I've always avoided creating factories because my applications are so simple that using a factory seems to needlessly complicate things, but I think I'll give it a try.

Comment: Using factories are often the answer to many questions regarding dependency injection ;-)